# Why base 64 string contains CCITTFAXDecode filter is not converting to image in Chrome and FireFox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, pdf, firefox, base64

I have the base64 string for the image which contains CCITTFAXDecode filter , while trying to convert the base64 string to image , it is not converting into the image in Chrome and FireFox browser but working fine in IE and Edge browsers. Please suggest me a solution for handling base64 string having images with CCITTFAXDecode filters in chrome and firefox.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add
       == 
at the end of base64 string...

And dont forget adding a type/header/MIME whatever you name it, like;

```
 data:image/gif;base64,yourbase64String
```

ref.
      https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64

Encode problem accurs sometimes